# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Verdana' is not available to the JVM. But I'm not using this font

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

while deploying this jasper file in a linux server. I've got the error :

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Verdana' is not available to the JVM.

But I'm not using this Font. I'm using "SansSerif" which is handled by linux.

PS. The Jasper file was first created by iReport 3.0 then I switched to iReport 5.1. But I recompiled it, and it worked perfectly in the localhost..

Any help please ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="EditerRecapAppro" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="842" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="fad38eb7-04c4-46b7-92d1-e002d57c48ee">
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <parameter name="pWhere" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["1=1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="pOrder" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="pCodeMagasin" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="pCodeDemandeur" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="pNumeroBS" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="pDatePC" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
    GLO_AS_APPRO_ENTETE.NUM_AUT_MVT AS NUM_APP,
    GLO_AS_APPRO_ENTETE.DATE_PEC AS DAT_APP,

    GLO_AS_APPRO_ENTETE.COD_SER AS CODE_SERVICE,
    (SELECT LIB_SERVICE_FR FROM GLO_AS_SERVICE WHERE GLO_AS_SERVICE.COD_SER = GLO_AS_APPRO_ENTETE.COD_SER AND GLO_AS_SERVICE.COD_ETAB = GLO_AS_APPRO_ENTETE.COD_ETAB) AS LIB_SERVICE,

    GLO_AS_APPRO_LIGNE.NUM_LIGNE AS NUM_LIG,
    GLO_AS_APPRO_LIGNE.COD_ARTC AS CODE_ARTICLE,
    (SELECT DES_ARTC_FR FROM GLO_AS_ARTICLE WHERE GLO_AS_ARTICLE.COD_ARTC = GLO_AS_APPRO_LIGNE.COD_ARTC) AS LIB_ARTICLE,
    GLO_AS_APPRO_LIGNE.COD_UNT AS UNIT,
    GLO_AS_APPRO_LIGNE.QTE_APP,

    (SELECT COD_MAG || ' - ' || LIB_MAG_FR FROM GLO_AS_MAGASINS WHERE GLO_AS_MAGASINS.COD_MAG = GLO_AS_APPRO_ENTETE.COD_MAG AND GLO_AS_MAGASINS.COD_ETAB = GLO_AS_APPRO_ENTETE.COD_ETAB) AS MAGASIN

FROM
    GLO_AS_APPRO_ENTETE join GLO_AS_APPRO_LIGNE ON
        GLO_AS_APPRO_ENTETE.NUM_AUT_MVT = GLO_AS_APPRO_LIGNE.NUM_AUT_MVT AND
        GLO_AS_APPRO_ENTETE.COD_ETAB = GLO_AS_APPRO_LIGNE.COD_ETAB AND
        GLO_AS_APPRO_ENTETE.EXERCICE = GLO_AS_APPRO_LIGNE.EXERCICE

WHERE $P!{pWhere} AND  GLO_AS_APPRO_ENTETE.VALID='O' AND GLO_AS_APPRO_ENTETE.STAT_APP = 'E'
ORDER BY $P!{pOrder}, GLO_AS_APPRO_LIGNE.NUM_LIGNE]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="NUM_APP" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="DAT_APP" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="CODE_SERVICE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LIB_SERVICE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="NUM_LIG" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="CODE_ARTICLE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LIB_ARTICLE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="UNIT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="QTE_APP" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="MAGASIN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="53" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e8affdf7-8f50-4194-ae2f-655ea31a165b" key="staticText-18" x="320" y="3" width="70" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{pCodeMagasin} != null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Code magasin :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="6a783e2e-c5b8-4231-bfff-c79d4c241421" key="textField-18" x="390" y="3" width="130" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{pCodeMagasin} != null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{pCodeMagasin}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e25887f6-51c0-435e-b949-a4b9340742f5" key="staticText-19" x="320" y="15" width="70" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{pCodeDemandeur} != null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Code demandeur :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="9425cadc-19ca-4f53-8f30-0000d1614f23" key="staticText-20" x="320" y="27" width="70" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{pNumeroBS} != null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Numéro bon de sortie :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="38de488c-a435-4a09-ba0c-35a238e8bbdd" key="textField-19" x="390" y="15" width="130" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{pCodeDemandeur} != null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{pCodeDemandeur}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="841888af-5a52-444f-b1f8-c5a66d66d1a0" key="textField-20" x="390" y="27" width="130" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{pNumeroBS} != null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{pNumeroBS}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="7199ea7e-c7c6-470a-b2d6-bab27507e03c" key="staticText-21" x="270" y="39" width="120" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{pDatePC} != null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date de prise en charge :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="a73a3da3-4438-4a29-806b-b08a343425cf" key="textField-21" x="390" y="39" width="130" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{pDatePC} != null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{pDatePC}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="60" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="00f4ca75-4054-4189-b47b-0b5f8eb44b47" key="staticText-1" mode="Opaque" x="126" y="30" width="295" height="15" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Service demandeur]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="6f8f52a5-00d6-4b28-ac8d-8b89ad67a30b" key="staticText-2" mode="Opaque" x="1" y="45" width="45" height="15" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[N°]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="c4937b21-c87b-4dd8-a3bd-daa607cfadb8" key="staticText-3" mode="Opaque" x="46" y="45" width="50" height="15" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e4997b00-e680-4dea-b9a0-31caf76812f7" key="staticText-6" mode="Opaque" x="421" y="30" width="50" height="30" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Type]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="6d7d880b-3fe8-4a11-8626-dbd396075e04" key="staticText-7" mode="Opaque" x="171" y="45" width="250" height="15" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box leftPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Designation]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="d60cbb17-00a2-4c53-8893-5787adc72132" key="staticText-8" mode="Opaque" x="126" y="45" width="45" height="15" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Code]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="97b495be-69a1-4b86-8be0-0d52ae3af3f4" key="staticText-10" mode="Opaque" x="1" y="30" width="125" height="15" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Demande]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e42335e4-aaa9-4dfa-bc2c-d41a2b33373d" key="staticText-11" mode="Opaque" x="96" y="45" width="30" height="15" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[N°]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="3a929df7-3200-4d55-bcb5-336ef11f93f9" key="staticText-12" mode="Opaque" x="471" y="30" width="310" height="15" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Article]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="03743f97-7dfc-42d9-ad5f-a8c5775f2364" key="staticText-13" mode="Opaque" x="471" y="45" width="50" height="15" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Code]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="07426d9a-1d21-41f1-b2c6-f8d61256500d" key="staticText-14" mode="Opaque" x="521" y="45" width="230" height="15" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box leftPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Designation]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="5d0ccba5-a561-4e96-b152-7a7a780fd006" key="staticText-15" mode="Opaque" x="781" y="30" width="40" height="30" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Quantité]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="80412bed-dc27-4c1b-ab1d-3fa3f24b0595" key="staticText-16" mode="Opaque" x="751" y="45" width="30" height="15" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Un.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="a793d6a7-e73e-4442-84fa-49e9f3685a32" key="staticText-17" mode="Opaque" x="1" y="10" width="70" height="15" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Magasin :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="4c307279-d5ee-46d7-9528-7ef8facf3fcf" key="textField-17" x="71" y="10" width="250" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MAGASIN}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="9dd3dae1-3ec0-47cb-bf83-86c3d102c184" key="textField-3" x="1" y="0" width="45" height="15"/>
                <box rightPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NUM_APP}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="99e93e13-78c9-4eeb-a5ae-91139d51a000" key="textField-4" x="46" y="0" width="50" height="15"/>
                <box leftPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DAT_APP}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="044fae08-595e-416c-a3a0-028f0c61b2c5" key="textField-8" x="421" y="0" width="50" height="15"/>
                <box leftPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="a3ffca82-df87-42ff-bb67-d2fc17843c53" key="textField-10" x="171" y="0" width="250" height="15"/>
                <box leftPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LIB_SERVICE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="94744acd-192d-400a-aa23-a6d33bcbc21d" key="textField-11" x="126" y="0" width="45" height="15"/>
                <box leftPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CODE_SERVICE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="6b81b174-2cc0-4708-9737-ed16b1d5fe93" key="textField-12" x="96" y="0" width="30" height="15"/>
                <box rightPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NUM_LIG}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="71bb1b34-5b82-4029-a85d-38e23162caa0" key="textField-13" x="471" y="0" width="50" height="15"/>
                <box leftPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CODE_ARTICLE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="0b1611b3-09b1-468e-8c45-4eab692c886e" key="textField-14" x="521" y="0" width="230" height="15"/>
                <box leftPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LIB_ARTICLE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="d776b9ac-6182-49e1-a0fc-7c0172c4063f" key="textField-15" x="781" y="0" width="40" height="15"/>
                <box rightPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{QTE_APP}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="2d9e05f4-cb39-4b3b-b1dd-22be9acab6f9" key="textField-16" x="751" y="0" width="30" height="15"/>
                <box leftPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{UNIT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: check the default font for elements , could be verdana which is not available by default in linux

Comment: Thank you Satya, do you know how to do that ?

Comment: The default font used by iReport 5.1 (That I'm using) is actually SansSerif. I don't know from where he gets this Verdana. Besides, all the text fields are explicitly set to "SansSerif", why would he look for a default font ?

Comment: check this http://javaskeleton.blogspot.in/2010/12/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by.html

Comment: @IoriYagami `while deploying this jasper file in a linux server` - What are you talking about?

Comment: I mean, my workstation is running on Windows XP, the server is running in Linux. I thought it would be useful to guess the problem cause, since there isn't the same Font list.. But as I said, I'm explicitly using "SansSerif" in all the fields..

Comment: @IoriYagami Which application raised this message (JasperReports Server, iReport, custom Java application)? What exporter did you use?

Comment: It's resolved. In fact, I'm using a template (I put any report as a subreport in this template). The template is generating a weird compilation error about : 

    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: An error has accurred compiling the subreport: C:\\Program Files\\Jaspersoft\\iReport-5.1.5\\ireport\\fonts (access denied)

Solution is to change the subreport_dir parameter this way : 

[link](http://pastebin.com/jxqNxngf)